# Preventing my image from going behind my div on smaller sized screens

Tags: html, css, image

I work on a larger sized monitor and immediately realized when pulling up my website on my laptop that my image had not resized its self next to my div but actually put its self under ? What should i do??

I have already tried to find answers online but didn't have much luck the site seems or run perfect basically only on my monitor but anything smaller and the photo starts to go under the text.

I am fairly new to all of this, picking up new skills while on lock-down so don't slam be too hard for any bad code just been struggling to figure this out

```css
    html, body {
     background-color: #fffaee;
     background-attachment: fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover; 
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    }
    
    #container {
     position: fixed;
     float: left;
     background: ;
     width: 424px;
     color: #000000;
     padding: 15px
    }
    
    h1 {
     font-size: 4vw
    }
    
    h2{
     background: #75c1f6;
     color:black;
     padding: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    p{
     font-size: 20px
    }
    
    a {
     color:#75c1f6;
     text-decoration: none; 
    }
    
    footer {
     position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #man {
     float: right;
    }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
              <head>
     

    <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta name="keywords" content="prank, pigeons, old man, interactive, art, teague, portfolio">
         <meta name="description" content="Frank loves to feed pigeons on his bench this is where he stays">
    
      <title>Frank</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="images/favicon.png">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Slab:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <div id="wrapper"></div>
     <div id="container">
     
    <h1>This Is Frank...</h1>
    <h2></h2>
     <P>Franks best friend is a pigeon.</P>
    
     <P>Frank wakes up every morning puts on his loafs and heads to the park to feed his friend.</P>
    
     <P>You've seen the old man on the park bench almost everyday while on your commute to work.</P>
    
     <p>One day while walking to work you stop to ask the old man how he's doing. He mumbles "His 
     name is Roger, help me feed him!" </p>  
     </div>
    
     <div id="man">
      <img src="images/grandpasmall.gif" alt="Old man on bench">
     </div>
    
     <footer>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/zed.head/" target="_blank">
       <img src="images/social-insta.png" alt="instagram">
       </a>
     </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set image `width` to `100%` like

```
img{
width : 100%;
height : auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with using pixels as the width of your container and image, if you need text or images to be resized try to use percentages or vh/vw for your it

Comment: you can write question codes and editing by your answer, for give best result. read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and get tour here : https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Set the following css to `img` and `#container`

```
img{
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
z-index : 1;
}
```

and for `#container`

```
#container{
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    background: ;
    width: 424px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 15px;
    z-index : -1;
}
```

Note : `z-index` property arranges the stack order of elements.For more details [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: This ended up just bringing my image intron of the text and also stretching it out

Comment: can you please provide a link to your project on online editor